# Hidden textbox layer showing in Show layout bounds mode in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Currently i am stuck with this problem.

When i hide a visible object in Toolbar in android,the layout boundary is still exists in the Show layout bounds mode of android.

First view

[image]

After make hidden by `.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

[image]

The boundary still alive in the  Show layout bounds mode.

Any help ?

Comment: Convert invisible to gone will remove line

Comment: @Jack i have already mentioned in my answer `.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: Check my images in answer

Comment: i have also checked programmatically and it is working fine for me

Comment: @Jack did you check it on `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check buttons below

Check original

[image]

Check invisible

[image]

check gone

[image]

Comment: I have already mentioned in my answer about `.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and problem is in android toolbar

Comment: Does forcing a re-layout solve the problem? Currently you are describing a "problem" which is only visible by a developer tool. Is there any other deeper case you want to solve?

Comment: @and_dev Our tester has posted posted this as a bug which we have to solve